# counting how many likes one user gives another

Tags: mysql

We recently installed a "like" extension on our phpbb message board, which is stored in a table we'll call "likes". I've been struggling to construct a query I've called "admirer", where it counts how many likes one user has given another. The output would ideally look like the following:

```
user_id_to | like count | user_id_from
---------------------------------------
    sam    |      6     |      mike
    sam    |      3     |      john
    mike   |      4     |      sam
    john   |      5     |      mike
```

Hopefully that helps. I have a query where it counts how many likes users get from a specified user_id in the WHERE clause as shown below:

```
SELECT users.username, COUNT(likes.like_id) AS love
FROM likes LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = likes.user_id_to
WHERE likes.user_id_from = [someone's user id]
GROUP BY users.username
ORDER BY love DESC;
```

However, I'm struggling to modify it without the WHERE, and have it display the count of likes from any user to any user. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the structure of your "likes" table?

Comment: like_id, user_id_from, user_id_to, like_time are the relevant attributes

Comment: Get rid of `id`, you have a 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY(user_id_from, user_id_to)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Group by both user IDs
2. Inner join to the users' table two times, use different alias to join it with different user id

   ```
   SELECT u_to.username as user_to, u_from.username as user_from, count(*) as like_count 
   FROM likes
   INNER JOIN users u_to on likes.user_id_to=u_to.user_id
   INNER JOIN users u_from on likes.user_id_from=u_from.user_id
   GROUP BY u_to.username, u_from.username
   ORDER BY like_count DESC
   ```

Comment: perfect, much appreciated